# Mocking es6 imports in javascript unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, import

I have a module that imports using ES6 object destructuring.

foo.js:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
```

I want to mock render in a unit test. I've tried two things, but neither of them seem to work.

Using a simple stub:

```
import * as reactDom from 'react-dom';
let renderStub = sinon.stub(reactDom, 'render');
```

Someone suggested [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), but I'm not sure of the correct way to stub a method from a node module. This is what I attempted:

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
proxyquire.noCallThru();
let foo = proxyquire('./foo', {
  'react-dom': {
    render: () => {}
   }
});
```

How do I mock this method correctly?

Comment: Your first example with the sinon stub should absolutely work, I have the exact same test `import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` and stub `sinon.stub(ReactDOM, 'render')` working no problems with the same `import {render} from 'react-dom'` in the test subject file. Could it be a red herring and there be some other issue?